# how to send multiple parameter in header using vue resource

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource

[image]

How can I send send multiple parameter in header through vue resource

```
// here is my post call but it send empty object to the server
this.$http.post('http://localhost/PostBranch', this.branch,
  Vue.http.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
  Vue.http.headers.post['Content-Type']='application/x-www-form-urlencoded').then((result) => {
    this.$router.push({path:'/Branches'});
  }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `URLParams()` and append all your parameters in it. In case of multiple parameters just keep on appending with the same key

```
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append(key1, value1);
params.append(key1, value2);
params.append(key2, value3);
```

> The URLSearchParams interface defines utility methods to work with the
>   query string of a URL.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)